# postgres cast to type from other schema extension

Tags: postgresql, ltree

### The situation:

I have a database with multiple schemas.
I've installed the ltree extension in public as such:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ltree schema public;
```

and then created the following function

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION public.strings_to_lquery_array(text[]) RETURNS lquery[]
    AS $$ select array_agg(('*.' || c::text || '.*')::lquery) from unnest($1) c $$
    LANGUAGE sql 
    immutable;
```

I then run the following code:

```
set search_path = 'content_api';
select public.strings_to_lquery_array(ARRAY['CURRICULUM']);
```

which gives the following error:

```
ERROR: type "lquery" does not exist 
LINE 1: select array_agg(('*.' || c::text || '.*')::lquery) from un...
```

I had assumed that when the function is in `public`, the ::lquery casting would also look in `public` ? but that doesn't seem to be the case.
how do I make this function work from any schema I'm in?
I found a workaround using `::public.lquery` but that just looks a little ugly. I'm also not fully understanding why postgres is doing what it's doing.

What is a better solution?

PS: assume I can't simply do: `set search_path = content_api,public;`

Comment: So what's wrong with `::public.lquery`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name nothing, i guess, I had just assumed wrongly, it seems, that a function in public, would also run in the public context, and was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.